# Summation of Sum Formula in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

I did a summation in one formula say Formula1. Now i created Formula2 which would do summation of Formula1 as Sum({@Formula1}).

But the crystal report gives the error as "The Field could not be summarized". I understand that summation of sum cannot be done, but i need to do this as Formula1 does summation of columns i.e. brings up Total and Formula2 brings up grand Total.

Please Help!

thanks

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us the actual code? (you can rename fields for anonymity.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Does your Formula1 always evaluate to a numeric value? For example, if you designed Formula1 to display "-" instead of "0", that would cause the problem for Formula2.
2. If this is a simple summation, you don't even need a Formula2.  Crystal has a built-in alternative.  On Formula1, go to **right-click->Insert->Summary** and choose where you want it (Group Footer or Report Footer)

Answer (score 0):

If you copy your summation field and paste it in the Report Footer, it will calculate a grand total--no need to do a sum(sum(field)).